# Force calculation of Cross Object formula to be used in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, formula, failing-tests

The basic gist of my issue is that I have a batch apex class that uses cross object formulas in some IF statements (Something like Contact.Account.FirstName).

The problem is that when I create the test class and insert all of the objects, the formula fields are *always* null. I've tried inserting them in testSetup, querying them after insertion, forcing the recalculateFormulas() and updating...nothing seems to work.

I also tried a test method to manually set the formula field, but since it's batch apex I don't think I can make the changes save and be used in the batch.

Any ideas?

The formula field (Subscription_Recipient__r is a master-detail to Contact):

```
Subscription_Recipient__r.Account.Owner.FirstName + " " + Subscription_Recipient__r.Account.Owner.LastName
```

The test code:

```
@isTest
private class ScheduleReassignmentTest{

@testSetup static void testSetup(){
    Profile p = [select id from profile where name='Standard User'];

    User u1 = new User();
    u1.FirstName = 'David';
    u1.LastName = 'Cromar';
    u1.Alias = 'dcrom';
    u1.Email = 'acoffey2@test.com';
    u1.Username = 'acoffey26515@test.com';
    //u1.UserRole = r;
    u1.CommunityNickname = 'testNick';
    u1.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
    u1.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    u1.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u1.ProfileId = p.Id;
    u1.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    insert u1;

    Account a1 = new Account();
    a1.OwnerId = u1.Id; //'0050x000000LSBV';
    a1.Name = 'Test Acct';
    insert a1;

    Contact c1 = new Contact();
    c1.LastName = 'LastName';
    c1.Account = a1;
    c1.Contact_Type__c = 'Current';
    insert c1;

    Subscription__c s1 = new Subscription__c();
    s1.PUB__c = 'DHSELAASA';
    s1.CUSTNUM__c = '112233';
    s1.Subscription_Recipient__c = c1.Id;
    s1.Owner_Test__c = NULL;
    s1.STATE__c = 'CT';
    s1.Product_Division__c = 'HCPro';
    insert s1;

    Subscription__c s2 = new Subscription__c();
    s2.PUB__c = 'DHSELAASA';
    s2.CUSTNUM__c = '112233';
    s2.Subscription_Recipient__c = c1.Id;
    s2.Owner_Test__c = NULL;
    s2.STATE__c = 'AK';
    s2.Product_Division__c = 'HCPro';
    insert s2;

    Subscription__c s3 = new Subscription__c();
    s3.PUB__c = 'DHSELAASA';
    s3.CUSTNUM__c = '112233';
    s3.Subscription_Recipient__c = c1.Id;
    s3.Owner_Test__c = NULL;
    s3.STATE__c = 'AL';
    s3.Product_Division__c = 'HCPro';
    insert s3;

    Subscription__c s4 = new Subscription__c();
    s4.PUB__c = 'DHSELAASA';
    s4.CUSTNUM__c = '112233';
    s4.Subscription_Recipient__c = c1.Id;
    s4.Owner_Test__c = NULL;
    s4.STATE__c = 'AR';
    s4.Product_Division__c = 'HCPro';
    insert s4;

    Subscription__c s5 = new Subscription__c();
    s5.PUB__c = 'ARGBO';
    s5.CUSTNUM__c = '112233';
    s5.Subscription_Recipient__c = c1.Id;
    s5.Owner_Test__c = NULL;
    s5.STATE__c = 'CT';
    s5.Product_Division__c = 'HCPro';
    insert s5;

    Subscription__c s6 = new Subscription__c();
    s6.PUB__c = 'DHHHCCSTD';
    s6.CUSTNUM__c = '112233';
    s6.Subscription_Recipient__c = c1.Id;
    s6.Owner_Test__c = NULL;
    s6.STATE__c = 'CT';
    s6.Product_Division__c = 'HCPro';
    insert s6;

    //a1.OwnerId = '00538000005Eagu';
    //update a1;

    Subscription__c s7 = new Subscription__c();
    s7.PUB__c = 'DHHHCCSTD';
    s7.CUSTNUM__c = '112233';
    s7.Subscription_Recipient__c = c1.Id;
    s7.Owner_Test__c = NULL;
    s7.STATE__c = 'CT';
    s7.Product_Division__c = 'HCPro';
    insert s7;

    //a1.OwnerId = '0050x000000LSBV';
    //update a1;

    Subscription__c s8 = new Subscription__c();
    s8.PUB__c = 'DHSELNAPP';
    s8.CUSTNUM__c = '112233';
    s8.Subscription_Recipient__c = c1.Id;
    s8.Owner_Test__c = NULL;
    s8.STATE__c = 'CT';
    s8.Product_Division__c = 'HCPro';
    insert s8;

    //a1.OwnerId = '00538000005T8di';
    //update a1;

    Subscription__c s9 = new Subscription__c();
    s9.PUB__c = 'DHSELNAPP';
    s9.CUSTNUM__c = '112233';
    s9.Subscription_Recipient__c = c1.Id;
    s9.Owner_Test__c = NULL;
    s9.STATE__c = 'CT';
    s9.Product_Division__c = 'HCPro';
    insert s9;

}

@isTest static void testClose() {
    List<Subscription__c> sl = [SELECT Id, Account_Owner__c, Owner_Test__c FROM Subscription__c];
    for(Subscription__c s : sl){
        System.debug(s.Account_Owner__c); //Is always null
    }

    Test.startTest();

    ScheduleReassignment SC = new ScheduleReassignment();
    String sch = '0 0 2 * * ?'; 
    System.schedule('ScheduleReassignment', sch, SC); //Code fails in this batch due to null value in Account_Owner__c formula

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Can you include the field formula and test code where you see the formula field as null?

Comment: Are you able to see System.debug() of source of formula fields and before/after recalculateFormulas() to see any clues, may be if you could please update question with those (with results) to see if it helps someone answer the question.

Comment: Yes, the system.debug() is what I'm outputting to see that they are null.

Comment: I've also added the code and formula

Comment: If you add the value `Subscription_Recipient__r.Account.Owner.LastName` to your query, do you get a non-null value in the debug?

Comment: No, if I add that to the query and then output it with a debug message I still get the same null response.

Comment: I was able to make a 'solution' by putting a Test.isRunningTest() block in the main code, and manually setting the formula field to what is needed to get the test to complete, but its more a workaround that doesn't fix the initial problem.

Comment: Try adding each individual step of the object relationship to your query, ie, `Subscription_Recipient__c, Subscription_Recipient__r.Id, Subscription_Recipient__r.Account, Subscription_Recipient__r.Account.OwnerId, Subscription_Recipient__r.Account.Owner.LastName`. Which steps are null?

Comment: Subscription_Recipient__c and Subscription_Recipient__r.Id both return the same Id as expected, every other value is null